# How to use log character decoding errors in Scala with scala.io.Codec

Tags: scala, character-encoding

Using Scala, I am reading a file with an expected encoding (in this case UTF-8) and would like to log coding errors. Simply inserting a replacement character “�” can be done like this:

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.io.Codec
import java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException
import java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction

object Main extends App {
    val codec = Codec("UTF-8").onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
    val s = Source.fromFile("test.txt")(codec)
    s.getLines foreach println
}
```

There is also another function on, `scala.io.Codec.onCodingException`, which takes a function of type `CharacterCodingException => Int`. However, it is unclear from the documentation what this `Int` represents – I am guessing it could be the Unicode value we should decode the invalid input as. I have tried this:

```
object Main extends App {
    val codec = Codec("UTF-8").onCodingException {
        case e: MalformedInputException => {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage())
            0xFFFD
        }
        case e =>  {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage())
            0xFFFD
        }
    }
    val s = Source.fromFile("test.txt")(codec)
    s.getLines foreach println
}
```

However, my handler is not invoked and the program crashes with `java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException`.

Any ideas how to log the error, insert a replacement character and continue decoding?